# Concept of Image pixels, resolution and magnification of image

Tags: image, camera, image-manipulation

I am trying to understand the relation between image pixels, their size, resolution and how changing the resolutions of an image results in the same image size but slight amount of blurriness. I referred to [this links](http://www.neocamera.com/article/image_size_resolution) but some doubts still remain:

1) So, what is the "commonly" accepted definition of "resolution"?

2) How(and Why) does changing the resolution of an image (say, a Desktop wallpaper) result in the same image size but a slight amount of blurriness? In this case, what definition of "resolution", "pixels" and "image size" are we talking about?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The image that is displayed on the screen is composed of thousands (or millions) of small dots; these are called pixels.

The number of pixels that can be displayed on the screen is referred to as the resolution of the image.
Image resolution is the detail an image holds.

> As the resolution goes up, the image becomes more clear. It becomes
>   sharper, more defined, and more detailed as well.

In addition to image size, the quality of the image can also be manipulated.  Here we use the word "compression".  An uncompressed image is saved in a file format that doesn't compress the pixels in the image at all.  Formats such as BMP or TIF files do not compress the image.

If you want to reduce the "file size" (number of megabytes required to save the image), you can choose to store your image as a JPG file and choose the amount of compression you want before saving the image.

These terms are explained in a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMAYZH1SB5Q)

Answer (score 0):

1. Put in simple words, resolution is simply the number of pixels(picture cells) contained in a horizontal/vertical axis. The more the pixels arranged in an axis, better the image. The formal definition can be easily availed on the web.
2. Changing the resolution simply means changing the number of pixels in the image.Higher resolution implies more pixels hence a more detailed image. Reducing the resolution of an image decreases the image size following either lossy or lossless compression algorithms. This further reduces the amount of information in the image leading to the blurriness or the jagged edges.Image size varies according to the degree of compression only. 'Pixels' and 'Resolution' remain what they had been explained.